# querying li elements returns NodeList conitaned nothing but should exist

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, axios, jsdom

##### Thank you for reading. I would appreciate any suggestions or information.

## What I'm doing

I'm making web scraping app **JSDOM** and **axios**. 
Trying to query all of `<a href="url">` and get href value.

## Problem

- #### Why `lists` 's length is 0?
- #### How can I get expected result? I want to get NodeList with 3 nodes
- #### Is there any points to be careful about JSDOM? I doubt this is some JSDOM problem.

```
// target HTML
<a href="#">getLink</a>
// It seems that this a tag is clickable and that gives #download-options "display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important". Does this affect what I'm doing?
<div id="download-options">
    <div class="panel-body">
        ::before
        <ul>
            <li><a href="url1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="url2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="url3"></a></li>
        </ul>
        ::after
    </div>
</div>
```

```
// My web-scraping code

let res = await axios.get('url')
conts dom = new JSDOM(res.data)

const ulist = dom.window.document.querySelector('#download-options > .panel-body > ul')
// => returns HTMLUListElement {}
// ulist.childElementCount => returns 1

const lists = ulist.querySelectorAll('li')
// => returns NodeList {}
// lists.length => returns 0 expected 3, so cannot forEach.
```

[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
[HTMLUlistElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUListElement)

## What I've tried

- I checked same query code from my google chrome browser developer console, then it returned what I expected. (I got NodeList with 3 nodes and could execute forEach and got all of hrefs value.)
- added user-agent for axios request.

##### Thank you for reading. I would appreciate any suggestions or information.

Comment: I found that the target web site doesn't return <li> in <ul> in first request.

Comment: It seems it need to be clicked to get <li>s. I will try use puppeteer instead of jsdom.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the target site doesn't respond with `<li>` in `<ul>` on first request to the site. I don't know why and how the site does this, but I think its related to cookies or cache things.

So I used puppeteer to visit the site's homepage and then target page. This solved the problem.

Codes are like below

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://example.com') //go to homepage to solve cache? problem
  await page.goto('https://example.com/targetpage'); // then go to actual target
  await page.waitForSelector('#download-options li'); // wait for it just in case

  const ul = await page.$("#download-options ul") 
  const lis = await ul.$$("li")

  for await (const li of lis ) {
    const a = await li.$('a')
    const hrefValue = await a.evaluate((el) => el.getAttribute('href'))
    console.log(hrefValue)
  }
  await browser.close();
})
```